# Get two fragment data by click the action menu item

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my case, i have used the FragmentActivity and contain two page of fragment.
initialize by this way.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The action bar item  is defined as below:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_edit"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Edit"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_save"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    android:showAsAction="withText|always"
    android:title="Save"/>
```

for example: i have one edittext at Fragment 1 and one edittext from Fragment 2.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and then the problem is how can i get the edittext data from the two fragment when i click the save action bar item.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to define actionbar items for fragments themselves, not for host FragmentActivity, by overriding fragments' `onCreateOptionsMenu` In this case you just override `onOptionsItemSelected` inside fragment and have direct access to your `EditText`.

The second solution will be to define method like  this:

```
class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    // ... some code here

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext2).getText();
    }
    // ... some code here
}
```

and access it in activity as the following:

```
Fragment fragment = getItem(1);
// ... some code here

// user clicked menu item:
if(fragment instanceof Fragment2) {
    CharSequence text = ((Fragment2)fragment).getText();
    // do whatever you want with text
}
```

Also you may define an interface with `getText()`, implement it in fragments, so you'll be able to get content from any desired fragment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you explain more about the Fragment fragment = getItem(1); as this method is inside the class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter, also it will return a new fragment, how can get the page after it input the text at the editext?

Comment: In this case I would suggest to do the same as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/2768194. You store references to created fragments and then call `Fragment fragment = adapter.getRegisteredFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem())`